# what is the close form expression for the update of $x_i$ in coordinate descent?

Tags: regression, lasso, gradient-descent

I am trying to derive the close form expression for the update of $\omega_i$ in coordinate descent for lasso, but I find it hard to proceed. Could you give me some hints?

$min_\omega\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-X_i\cdot\omega)^2+\lambda\|\omega\|_1$
I need to find $\omega_i = ?$

Comment: Also see a full derivation here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/coordinate-descent-soft-thresholding-update-operator-for-lasso/351134#351134

Answer (score 1):

You can find the derivation in different forms at the following links:

- [on stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/derivation-of-closed-form-lasso-solution)
- [on this blog](http://jocelynchi.com/a-coordinate-descent-algorithm-for-the-lasso-problem)
- [on this notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/zyxue/stanford-cs229/blob/master/previous_cs229/ps3/l1-regularization-for-least-squares-and-coordinate-descent.ipynb)