# Coordinate descent for lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

I was reading abut the coordinate descent procedure for lasso. I have to write about it. I understood how it works but what I don't get are the formulas. Everywhere I see some additions or something is different.

in [these slides](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt/lectures/coord-desc.pdf)  page 14 the $\beta$ update is:

$\beta_i = \frac{S_\lambda}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2} \left ( \frac{X_i^T (y-X_{-i}\beta_{-i})}{X_i^T X_i} \right )=\frac{S_\lambda}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2} \left ( \frac{X_i^T (y-X_{-i}\beta_{-i})}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2} \right )$

What I don't really understand here is why is the soft thresholding being divided by $\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2$?
Should then the coefficient update be:

$\tilde{\beta}_j(\lambda)\leftarrow \frac{1}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2} S \left (\frac{X_i^T (y-X_{-i}\beta_{-i})}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2} ,\lambda\right )$ ?

I would very much appreciate any clarification, or any suggestion of what I could read to understand it better.

Comment: Based on the slide you pointed to, I think $||X_i||_2^2$ is in the subscript, i.e. $S_{\frac{\lambda}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2}}$ instead of $ \frac{S_\lambda}{\left \| X_i \right \|_2^2}$. I previously derived and implemented L1 from scratch [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/zyxue/stanford-cs229/blob/master/previous_cs229/ps3/l1-regularization-for-least-squares-and-coordinate-descent.ipynb).

Comment: @zyxue thank you a lot now it makes more sense. I checked your derivation what I don't get is in the 3d line of your equation, is there a 2 missing? should it be $\frac{1}{2}2(X\bar{\theta}+X_i\theta_i-y)^T(X\bar{\theta}+X_i\theta_i-y) +lambdaTerms$ ?

Comment: No, that first equation just expands $J(\theta)$, not taking its derivative.

Answer (score 1):

For the full derivation - have a look at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/coordinate-descent-soft-thresholding-update-operator-for-lasso?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To answer your question shortly

> What I don't really understand here is why is the soft thresholding
>   being divided by $‖X_i‖_2^2$? Should then the coefficient update be

This happens when the data you are working with has not been *normalized* before the coordinate descent. Going through the derivation you find that the optimization problem uses sub-differentials and that the solution is of the form

\begin{aligned}
     \begin{cases}
       \theta_j = \frac{\rho_j + \lambda}{z_j}  & \text{for} \ \rho_j < - \lambda \\
       \theta_j = 0 & \text{for} \ - \lambda \leq \rho_j \leq \lambda \\
       \theta_j = \frac{\rho_j - \lambda}{z_j}  & \text{for} \ \rho_j > \lambda 
    \end{cases}
\end{aligned}

We recognize this as the *soft thresholding* function $\frac{1}{z_j} S(\rho_j , \lambda)$ where $\frac{1}{z_j}$ is a normalizing constant which is equal to $1$ when the data is normalized, i.e. $z_j = \sum_{i=1}^m (x_j^{(i)})^2 = ‖X_i‖_2^2$

#### Coordinate descent update rule:

Repeat until convergence or max number of iterations:

- For $j = 0,1,...,n$
- Compute $\rho_j = \sum_{i=1}^m x_j^{(i)}  (y^{(i)}  - \sum_{k \neq j}^n \theta_k x_k^{(i)} ]$
- Compute $z_j = \sum_{i=1}^m (x_j^{(i)})^2$
- Set $\theta_j = \frac{1}{z_j} S(\rho_j, \lambda)$

Now in practice, you will find that most people and most books tell you to normalize the data before you perform lasso and coordinate descent. I will tell you that when I have implemented lasso via coordinate descent - I could only make it work with normalized data. But that might be my own failings only.

Comment: Is there any reason that coordinate decent is prefered?  Why people say coordinate desent is fast for L1 problem?