# Statistical Learning With Sparsity: Direct Inspection of the LASSO function

Tags: regression, lasso

In the book Statistical Learning with Sparsity: The Lasso and Generalizations, in section 2.4.1, they mention that the absolute value of $\beta$ has no derivative at $\beta=0$, therefore they proceed by direct inspection to determine the value of $\beta$ in a piece-wise manner, which is shown in 2.10.  Does anyone know what they mean by direct inspection? Did they draw the function out and inspect it? I can't see how they arrived at 2.10 from inspecting 2.9.

[image]

Comment: I can't help with the notion of inspection.. but I have given a full derivation with all of the steps and assumptions here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/coordinate-descent-soft-thresholding-update-operator-for-lasso/351134#351134 -> hope it helps