# How is the lasso orthogonal design case solution derived?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

In orthogonal design of lasso, we get  $\hat{\beta}_j^{\text{lasso}} = 0 \text{ if abs}(\hat{\beta}_j) \le \lambda /2$. **WHY?**

I've seen the answer and derived it myself, but don't know why.

We begin with definition of lasso,
$$\hat{\beta}^{\text{lasso}} = \underset{x} {\arg\min}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( y_i - \sum_{j=1}^{p}\beta_{ij}x_{ij} )^2 + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{p} |\beta_j|  $$

In orthogonal design case where $X^T X= I$, $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^{T}y = X^Ty$

\begin{align} L(\beta, \lambda) & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( y_i - \sum_{j=1}^{p}\beta_{ij}x_{ij} )^2 + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{p} |\beta_j| \\
 & = (Y - X \beta)^T(Y - X \beta) + \lambda \mathbf{I}_p \text{ abs}(\beta) \\
 & = Y^TY -2\hat{\beta}^T\beta + \beta^T \beta+ \lambda \mathbf{I}_p \text{ abs}(\beta) \\
 & = Y^TY + \sum_{j=1}^{p} L_j(\beta_j, \lambda)
\end{align}

where $L_j(\beta_j, \lambda) = -2 \hat{\beta}_j \beta_j + 2\beta^2_j + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j)$.

Leave aside $\beta_j=0$, take dereivative w.r.t. $\beta_j$ for abs$(\beta_j) > 0$,
$$\frac{L_j(\beta_j, \lambda)}{\partial \beta_j}  = -2 \hat{\beta}_j + 2\beta_j + \lambda \text{ sign}(\beta_j)$$

and $\hat{\beta}^{\text{lasso}}$ is either zero or solve,
$$\beta_j + \lambda \text{ sign}(\beta_j) / 2 = \hat{\beta}_j,$$

which is,
$$
\hat{\beta}^{lasso}_j = 
\begin{cases}
    \hat{\beta}_j - \lambda/2, & \text{if } \hat{\beta}_j > \lambda/2\\
    \hat{\beta}_j + \lambda/2, & \text{if } \hat{\beta}_j < -\lambda/2
\end{cases}
$$

**My question is the following derivation,**

If abs$(\hat{\beta}_j) \le \lambda / 2$, we get
$$L_j(\beta, \lambda) 
= -2 \hat{\beta}_j \beta_j + 2\beta^2_j + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) 
\ge -\lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j)
\ge 0 = L_j(0, \lambda)$$
and, we can tell $\hat{\beta}_j^{\text{lasso}} = 0 \text{ if abs}(\hat{\beta}_j) \le \lambda /2$ **(Why? How can you tell?)**

**Why $\mathbf{\hat{\beta}_j^{\text{lasso}} = 0}$?** The explanation of $L_j(\beta_j, \lambda) \ge L_j(0, \lambda)$ does not seem to justify the reason.

Answer (score 6):

Your derivation is not really precise, you are not really taking the derivative, but the [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative), the function $|x|$ is not differentiable when $x = 0$. The subderivative $s$ of the absolute value when $x =0$ is $s\in [-1, 1]$

Thus, the conditions you derived are for the case where $\hat{\beta}^{lasso}_j \neq 0$ where indeed the subdifferential of the absolute value is equal the sign. But now consider the case $\hat{\beta}^{lasso}_j = 0$. By the KKT conditions, this will happen when $-\hat{\beta}_j^{ols} + s\frac{\lambda}{2} = 0$ which implies $|\hat{\beta}_j^{ols}| \leq \frac{\lambda}{2}$, since  $s\in [-1, 1]$ when $\hat{\beta}^{lasso}_j = 0$.

**The LASSO problem**

For the sake of completeness I will write down the the lasso problem here. Our goal is to minimize

$$\min_{\beta} || Y - X\beta||_2^2 + \lambda||\beta||_1$$

where $||\cdot||_1$ is the $l_1$ norm. This a [convex optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) problem, and the optimum is characterized by the [KKT conditions](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F15/lectures/12-kkt.pdf):

$$
-2X'(Y - X\beta) + \lambda s = 0
$$

where $s$ is the [subgradient](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/subgrad.pdf) of the $l_1$ norm, that is, $s_j = sign(\beta_j)$ if $\beta_j \neq 0$ and $s_j \in [-1, 1]$ if $\beta_j = 0$.

In the orthonormal case, $X'Y = \hat{\beta}^{OLS}$ and $X'X = I$, simplifying this to:

$$
-2\hat{\beta}^{OLS} +2\beta + \lambda s = 0
$$

Thus, consider the case where the solution would be $\beta_j = 0$. For this to be true we must have that $-2\hat{\beta}_j^{OLS} + \lambda s_j = 0$ which implies $|\hat{\beta}_j^{OLS}| \leq \frac{\lambda}{2}$, since $s_i \in [-1, 1]$. Since this a convex program, KKT is sufficient, and the condition works both ways, that is, $|\hat{\beta}_j^{OLS}| \leq \frac{\lambda}{2} \implies \beta_j = 0$

Comment: I renamed loss function S to L, so the notation more consistent. But, why is $L \in [-1, 1]$? Which step of the derivation are you referring to?

Comment: The absolute value does not have a derivative when $x =0$. Recall that a derivative is the slope of the tangent line and at zero the absolute value has a "corner", you might want to check this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991475/why-is-the-absolute-value-function-not-differentiable-at-x-0/991559). But we can extend the idea to subderivatives, and in this case it's not a single number, but a set, consisting of the slope of all lines below the function that touches the point. You might want to check this https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf

Comment: The part of the derivation I'm referring to is  $-2 \hat{\beta}_j + 2\beta_j + \lambda \text{ sign}(\beta_j)$, where this only true for $\beta_j \neq 0$. For the case where $\beta_j = 0$, which is the case of your doubt,  this should read $-2 \hat{\beta}_j + \lambda s$ where $s$ is the subdifferential  of the absolute value at $0$, which is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I was reading that this $L_j(\beta, \lambda) 
= -2 \hat{\beta}_j \beta_j + 2\beta^2_j + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) 
\ge -\lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j)
\ge 0 = L_j(0, \lambda)$ implies $\hat{\beta}_j^{lasso} = 0$. Why is that?

Comment: I'm still reading your explanation with the KTT condition, which I think is different from my derivation?

Comment: @user13985 the only difference is that the derivative of $|\beta_j|$ is not defined when $\beta_j  = 0$, so you need the subderivative. Then you get the inequality you want for the optimality condition when $\beta_j = 0$.

Comment: I don't get it! In your comment above, if $\beta_j = 0$, then the first two terms in $-2 \hat{\beta}_j \beta_j + \beta^2_j + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) $ both goes away, so, how did you get $-2\hat{\beta}_j + \hat{\lambda} s$?

Comment: I think I also have a typo. $-2 \hat{\beta}_j \beta_j + 2\beta^2_j + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) $ should be $-2 \hat{\beta}_j \beta_j + \beta^2_j + \lambda \text{ abs}(\beta_j) $

Comment: @user13985 what I said refers to the derivative, the equation below that.

Comment: So, the derivative per above is 0 = $-2\hat{\beta}_j + 2 \beta_j + \lambda s$, where s = sign($\beta_j)$. If we let $\beta_j = 0$, then we get $0 = -2\hat{\beta}_j + \lambda s$, we can't solve this! I'm so confused!

Comment: Also, here we are discussing the case abs$\hat{\beta_j} \le \lambda/2$, which led to the conclusion $\hat{\beta}_j^{lasso} = 0$. I don't see how the above leads to this relationship.

Comment: @user13985 the question here is "under what condition is zero a solution?". By the KKT conditions, for zero to be a solution we must have $-2\hat{\beta}_j + \lambda s = 0$ which implies $|\hat{\beta}_j|\leq \frac{\lambda}{2}$, since $s \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Aren't we just taking derivatives and solving for the unknown? It's simple algebra. What's KKT conditions doing here? Actually, could you derive the answer step-by-step. I just don't see it! Also, is s=sign($\hat{\beta}$), is that what you mean?

Comment: @user13985 KKT conditions are the conditions for optimality of convex optimization problems. I wrote down the derivation step by step in the answer, but it seems you would benefit from studying optimization of non-differentiable functions. $s = sign(\beta)$ only if $\beta \neq 0$, when $\beta = 0$, then $s \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Why $s_j = [-1, 1]$ if $\beta_j = 0$? The vertex of a absolute value function f(x)=|x| at its vertex is not differentiable.

Comment: @user13985 this is the first thing I explained, we are talking about **subgradients**.

Comment: To differentiate $|\hat{\beta}_j|$, why can't we do piecewise function, then take derivative? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @user13985 these comments are already extending too much, I would be happy to answer other questions, but if they are properly asked in different questions.

Comment: I just want to know the answer to my original question. **How the last inequality works.** You don't need to answer anything else. Why it leads to zero as the solution. Yes, you took it to a different route with KKT, I'll look at that. But, I'm just trying to understand how that inequality holds, 'cause to me, it doesn't imply $\beta^{lasso}$ is zero!

Comment: @user13985 you can simply enumerate all cases with $\beta_j \neq 0$  and check that the loss is greater than the loss with $\beta_j = 0$.

Comment: I was hoping you can provide the explanation. Ok, I will do it. Choose $\hat{\beta}_j = \lambda / 4$, $L_j(\beta, \lambda) = -\lambda/2 + \beta_j^2 + \lambda \ge -\lambda + \lambda = 0 = L_j(0, \lambda) $. So, how does this say anything about $\beta^{\text{lasso}} = 0$ ?

Comment: I think you just re-wrote page 5 of Tibshirani's notes: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/sparsity.pdf with my notation in it? I want to understand why and how it's derived.