# Regularization of linear regression problem

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, linear-model, regularization

Consider a vector $a \in R^n$. I want to know how I can find analytically the solution of the following optimization problem: $x^* = argmin_{x \in R^n} f(x)$, where $f(x) = ||x-a||_{2}^2 + \lambda ||x||_1$, $\lambda > 0$ and $||.||_p$ is the p-norm in $R^n$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to CrossValidated. Does this question and its answers help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766811/l1-regularized-unconstrained-optimization-problem?

Comment: This might be another related question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375838/analytical-solution-to-a-simple-l1-norm-problem

Comment: @VincentGuillemot my question is to find $x^*$ which is $argmin_x f(x)$. The post you sent me is about $min f(x)$

Comment: This is a special case of LASSO problem with orthogonal design matrix. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323234/how-is-the-lasso-orthogonal-design-case-solution-derived) answers your question (your $X = I$)