# What is the LASSO regression model solution where X is not orthonormal?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, regularization, supervised-learning

If you have the LASSO with non orthonormal X problem, what is its solution?
In othe words, how can I obtain the $$\beta$$ weight values?
We need the mathematical derivation in order to front another, more complex, problem.

Comment: There's no closed form solution

Comment: There is no restriction to orthonormal $X$ in Lasso.  Why do you think there is?

Comment: @jbowman, there isn't a restriction, but when X **is** orthonormal, [there is a closed-form solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17781/232706)